# Use getattr inside of another getattr

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I use `getattr` method inside of another `getattr`?
I want to write something like that:

```
    my_attr = 'group.getattr(name)'
    my_list = list()
    for q in queryset_for_table:
        y = getattr(q, my_attr, None)
        my_list.append(y)
```

How can i write `my_attr` string correct?

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Do you want to get the `name` attribute of the `group` attribute of each `q`?

Comment: Florian Rhiem, exactly!

Comment: John Gordon, i have used that variant, but it wasn't works. By following this variant i have get only `None` as result. But i definitely sure `name` field is exist and isn't `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to gather the `name`s of the `group`s of all `q` objects that have a `group` attribute. If so, the following code will work by splitting the desired operation into two readable steps:

```
my_list = list()
for q in queryset_for_table:
    group = getattr(q, 'group', None)
    if group is not None:
        my_list.append(group.name)
```

If all `q` objects have a `group` attribute, you could also use:

```
my_list = list()
for q in queryset_for_table:
    my_list.append(q.group.name)
```

---

For arbitrary nested attributes the following should work:

```
def get_nested_attributes(object, attributes):
    for attribute in attributes:
        objects = [getattr(o, attribute, None) for o in objects]
    return objects

my_list = get_nested_attrs(queryset_for_table, ('group', 'name'))
```

This solution iterates over the attributes. You start with your queryset, then get the groups, then get the group names.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but i want to use just one string with my parameters. I do not need two loops

Comment: There are no two loops there, only one loop and one if-block. Is there a reason why you want to avoid the if block? Do all `q` objects have a `group` attribute or only some?

Comment: Yes, all the q objects has group attribute. But there is only part of my function for different querysets with different parameters. I get my parameters as list of strings. And want to get sometimes attributes not only from current object. For this i am trying to write some string `my_attr` with magic string to get some attribute from another attribute.

Comment: I added a solution for arbitrary nested attributes. If you only ever need 2 attributes, you could also use: `getattr(getattr(q, my_attr1, None), my_attr2, None)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer!
I need to use `'firstfield__secondfield__thirdfield'` for creating multiply samples in python.
For my example inside of the problem description i should write:
`queryset_for_table.values('group__name')`
Maybe it will help someone there